# Retrofit Image Upload give Error

Tags: android, http-headers, multipartform-data, retrofit

I am trying to upload an image using the Retrofit library but cant find any success in doing so;

Here is my code:

```
File photo = new File(picturePath);
    TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", photo);
    GroupTravelServer serverObject = Utils.getRetroFitAdapter();
    serverObject.uploadImage(Utils.getAuthHeader(getActivity()), "multipart/form-data", tripId,
            typedFile, new Callback<ChatMessageModel>() {
        @Override
        public void success(C
```

Here is my interface method:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v1/messages")
void uploadImage(@Header(PARAM_AUTHORIZATION) String authorization,
                 @Header(PARAM_CONTENT_TYPE) String contentType, @Part("tripId") String tripId,
                 @Part("image") TypedFile image, Callback<ChatMessageModel> callback);
```

This is the path that is been passed:

```
picturePath=  /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/2014-05-19 17.15.43.jpg
```

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error

with the following StackTrace:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:416)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
        at retrofit.Utils.streamToBytes(Utils.java:43)
        at retrofit.Utils.readBodyToBytesIfNecessary(Utils.java:81)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter.logAndReplaceResponse(RestAdapter.java:494)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter.access$600(RestAdapter.java:114)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:370)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:264)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:315)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

D/Retrofit﹕ ----

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the root problem, but you should provide TypedFile with the mimetype of the file you're uploading. In this case that should be:

    new TypedFile("image/jpeg", photo);

Comment: Hello check the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/42291172/5488468
it works for me